# React native app auth (android) shows two apps with same redirect scheme?

Tags: android, react-native, oauth, url-scheme

[Click here to view screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0dwE.png)

I am using react native app auth with Azure active directory and in android after redirecting back to the app, two apps are shown (like in the above screenshot) , if i select the correct app the app works as expected, but if i select the other, the app crashes. How can i fix this issue and show only one app!

```
const config = {
  issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-id',
  clientId: 'your-client-id',
  redirectUrl: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
  scopes: [], // ignored by Azure AD
  additionalParameters: {
    resource: 'your-resource'
  }
};

// Log in to get an authentication token
const authState = await authorize(config);

// Refresh token
const refreshedState = await refresh(config, {
  refreshToken: authState.refreshToken,
});
```

Comment: You have either more than 1 app, or more than 1 activity in this app that claim to open the same url in your android manifest.  If its more than 1 activity, fix that.  If its more than one app, uninstall the other.

Comment: hey @GabeSechan thanks for the help, but that is not the issue :(

Comment: It is. That's literally the only way to get that dialog, multiple activities can open the same intent

Answer (score 1):

Try not to put **"scheme"** option into app.json and use a redirectUrl like this.

```
<your.package.identifier>://oauthredirect
```

According to this [AppAuth OAuthRedirect](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/app-auth/#appauthoauthredirect), AppAuth uses for scheme the android.package identifier. For example if your package.identifier is **"your.company.app"**, use a redirectUrl like this: `your.company.app://oauthredirect`. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be doubled config added according to documentation: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#android-setup

One way is to add link in android/app/build.gradle file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      appAuthRedirectScheme: 'io.identityserver.demo'
    ]
  }
}
```

Another way is to add config to AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
    tools:node="replace">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.example.app"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you add both it will be registered twice, hence select app popup will appear after login.